# Can't freeze fs inside docker container

Tags: linux, docker

I don't understand why I'm getting the "Operation not permitted" issue inside my docker container.

[app@445c2ddbdac5 /]$ fsfreeze -f /home/app/test
fsfreeze: /home/app/test: freeze failed: Operation not permitted

Do you know how to solve it ?

Thanks per advance

Comment: switch to user root :)

Comment: Not working too :(

Comment: How is volume `/home/app/test` mounted to container? Isn't it readonly or NFS? Can you try `fsfreez -f .....` from docker host?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to run the container in the pod as a privilaged one.